# Is it possible to hide certain products from displaying in the search results

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, search

I was wondering if it's possible to hide certain products from the woocommerce/theme search box/field.

I have about 150 products on my website, which have a price & a product picture.
These are the products I want shown on my website, aswell in the search results.

Now I've also got around 250 other products which lack a product image, or don't have a price, or which just aren't available at that time.
--> These products are "Concepts" at this moment.

Now I came to the conclusion that these products also were showing in my search box at the top of my website when I entered a string that these products contained.

If there is a way around this, feel free to let me know!
Thanks in advance.

Kind Regards

Comment: Are your products visible on front end? i mean are they published or not

Comment: As far as I know it's not published. The publish button is still available to click.

I took a screenshot (sorry my WP install is in Dutch, I tried translating the important strings)
https://i.gyazo.com/8ef6cce20aeb8322a9cc8210e89f564a.png

Comment: search in an incognito(private) window

Comment: I tried, I'm still able to find the products when searching in incognito mode with Google Chrome. So I guess it's not a chaching issue? :S

Comment: not concerned with cache, but wp_query includes protected posts when admin is logged in. Are you using custom query for search page?

Comment: Wait, admin is logged in, a bell is starting to rinkle.

I have to be logged in as admin because the site is in maintenance mode at this moment. So the only way for me to view the website is if i'm logging in as admin.

I'll make a normal user (no admin privileges) and login on that account, maybe that way I won't be able to see conceptual items.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68750/discussion-between-piyush-rawat-and-arne-de-belser).

Comment: sum it up as an answer, so that others can see it aswell

Answer (score 0):

The answer:

It's possible to put a product on:

```
Visibility: Private
```

This will make sure only admins are able to view this product.